# Reading events of the inner Solidity contract with Web3

Tags: solidity, web3js, dapp-development, abi

Let's say I've got

```
contract A {
    event E();

    function a() public {
        emit E();
    }
}

contract B {
    A private a;

    function b() public {
        a();
    }
}
```

Now my Dapp is calling the method `b`:

```
const contractB = new web3.eth.Contract(BAbi, address)
const receipt = await contractB.methods.B().send({ /* options */ })
const {events, logs} = receipt
```

`events` will contain one encoded event. The event will not have an event name and not decoded arguments (in the `returnValues` field). Thinking of it this makes sense cause the event description wasn't put into the ABI of contract `B` but into the ABI of `A`. So the event description wasn't event supplied to a contract.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a straight forward way to solve it by extending the contract `B` ABI with the events of contract `A`. `A` is inside of `B`, so `B` can call to `A` methods and trigger `A` events. While `A`'s methods are encapsulated, `A`'s events are not. By this line of thinking in makes sense to include `A`'s events in `B`.

This can be done manually by a copy-paste or with code:

```
const eventsA = extractEvents(AAbi)
const extendedAbi = [...BAbi, ...eventsA]
const contractB = new web3.eth.Contract(extendedAbi, address)
const receipt = await contractB.methods.B().send({ /* options */ })
```

or even in a more incautious way:

```
const extendedAbi = [...BAbi, ...AAbi]
```

Any thoughs about this pattern? Other solution?

Comment: That's a very clever hack!